# How to notify activity when a fragment's edit text has been edited (Android)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have an edittext in one of my fragments.
I also have a String field in my activity that starts the fragment, and every time the text changes in the edittext, I want to change the string in my activity accordingly but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an interface like this

   ```
   interface OnDataChangeListener {
        fun onChange(string: String)
   }
   ```
2. In your fragment's constructor pass an instance of this interface as a parameter

   ```
   class MyFragment(val onDataChangeListener: OnDataChangeListener): Fragment
   ```
3. Now when the text changes in the edit text, call this interface's method

   ```
   editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            onDataChangeListener.onChange(s.toString())
        }
    })
   ```
4. Now implement this interface in our activity

   ```
   class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnDataChangeListener {

     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

          AppUtils.addFragment(this, MyFragment(this), R.id.fragment_container)
     }

     override fun onChange(string: String) {
          val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
          textView.text = string
     }
   }
   ```

That's it. This should give you the required output.

Comment: Thanks! It's basically https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#CommunicatingWithActivity combined with TextWatcher, nice. I didn't add the interface in my fragment's constructor though, what is that for?

Comment: Interface is for sending the callback to some other component. Whenever we have to send some data from fragment back to the activity, we use interface. This way your fragment is not directly coupled with your activity and you can re-use this fragment in some other activity/fragment as well.

Comment: Oh I understand that, but I don't know why we have to do step 2, it seems to work without it?

Comment: In my opinion, it wouldn't work without step 2 because, to actually call functions of that interface(that is Step 3), we need a reference of a class implementing the interface.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#EventCallbacks Ohh I think maybe it's working because I added the onAttach() method shown here? I'm pretty new to this but..?

Comment: "Then the activity that hosts the fragment implements the OnArticleSelectedListener interface and overrides onArticleSelected() to notify fragment B of the event from fragment A. To ensure that the host activity implements this interface, fragment A's onAttach() callback method (which the system calls when adding the fragment to the activity) instantiates an instance of OnArticleSelectedListener by casting the Activity that is passed into onAttach()". That's from that link

Comment: Oh Okay. We can do it this way as well. I wasn't familiar with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface that the `Activity` implements and pass it to your `Fragment`. Then, add a `TextWatcher` to the `EditText` with `editText.addTextWatcher()` inside your `Fragment`, and notify the listener inside `onTextChanged`. This approach is based off the [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#CommunicatingWithActivity).